# I tried adding Font Awesome icons on my webpage but it's not working

Tags: html, css

I am not quite sure how to do this. I've followed the instructions to the letter but it's not working. I've looked through other tutorials but it seems that I can't find an answer that I could understand.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="paws.css">
    <link href="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
    <body>

        <div class="prof-box">
            <img src="mrmcquack.jpg" class="prof-pic">

            <h1>RABIDWUFF</h1>
            <h5>An awkward human being who just wants 
                <br>to be a better version of herself.</h5>
            <p>My passion is sleeping.</p>
        </div>

        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>

    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my css

```
    html { 
    background: url(desk.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }

  .prof-box {
     width: 700px;
     height: 500px;
     background-image: url(burnt.png);
     padding: 40px;
     color: black;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 110px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .prof-pic {
     border-radius: 50%;
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     margin-top: 59px;
 }

 h1 {

     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: 4;
     font-size: 40px;
 }

 p {
     font-size: 20px;
 }

 h5 {
     font-size: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: You probably have errors in your browser console. Use the _Tools > Developer Tools_ menu option or `<F12>` to open the browser dev tools console. Copy the errors that are shown (if any) and edit them into your question.

Comment: This question should not have been downvoted. There is nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: @gibberish All the answers are getting downvotes as well. Seems weird. Most likely the file path to the font awesome css is the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see one, and possibly two, problems.

First, you changed the initial font-awesome class from "fa" to "fas, far, fab" - you can't do that. You can ADD those as additional classes, but not remove the "fa" class.

Second, your font-awesome.css file may not be found. Replace the static file with the version on the CDN, and that will be a good test for you.

Replace this:

```
<link href="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

With this:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And replace this:

```
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
<i class="far fa-user"></i>
<i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
```

with this:

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
<i class="fa fa-user-secret"></i>
<i class="fa fa-github-square"></i>
```

---

To add the additional classes, you can do this:

```
<i class="fa fas fa-user"></i>
<i class="fa far fa-user-secret"></i>
<i class="fa fab fa-github-square"></i>
```

Answer (score -1):

firstly check your font awesome css file it should load proper if it doesn't work than try live font awesome css link given below :

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using the files on your server you have to check for the files paths, 
so if you have your font awesome css on this path

```
<link href="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

you should have all the other files on this path:

```
/static/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot
/static/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg
/static/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf
/static/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff
```

and you are using far and fas so you have to have the others files aswell:

```
/static/webfonts/fas-brands-400.eot
/static/webfonts/fas-brands-400.svg
etc...
```

check if you have all the files on the proper location